What is the efficiency of a Franklin's Bells device?
Just sitting here day dreaming, and I had a hypothesis that a Franklin's Bells device is likely extremely efficient. Its mostly a gut feeling though based on its low surface area contact point between the ball and bell, the rather small amount of current used and it's slow moving nature. Typically devices which accelerate slowly or use their energy slowly seem more efficient, but its just a guess.
What I'd like to know is if anyone ever measured it. Some portion of the energy of course is getting lost to friction and heat, and the rest goes into propelling the ball. So what percentage of energy is used in propelling the ball vs lost as waste heat/noise/etc?
As a bonus if we can compare this to the efficiency of other electro-mechanical devices that would be an interesting addition.
My own attempts at searching for an answer provides absolutely nothing of use.
Additional Info
Someone asked as a follow up the following question

"You used the word, efficient. That word usually denotes a ratio--typically, the ratio of some output from a system to an input. What input and output did you have in mind?"

I'd like to answer that..
I am viewing the input as the energy source charging the two bells that ultimately propel the metal ball. In the case of the Oxford Electric Bell, for example, the input would be the two battery pyles.
As for the output to the system that would be how much energy makes it into the ball for propulsion. Obviously since eventually all energy will turn to heat I would consider any energy lost before reaching the ball and imparting a force to it would be considered waste heat/radiation. So some examples of waste heat would be any leaked electrostatic energy from the bells, and RF or field energy lost from the bells due to RFI coming from the bells, any energy lost as heat from the heating of the bells or as heat from the conductors as energy flows, as well as energy lost due to the static contact point friction of the ball being in contact with the bell, energy lost as heat from the vibrations of the bells due to the ball hitting it, and perhaps other places.
What I would not consider waste heat, however, would be friction with the ball with the air as it moves, energy lost through any sound made by the ball itself, energy lost via friction within the string itself swinging back and forth, or any fields or EM radiation lost directly from the ball itself.
Now obviously I know I'm asking for a rather detailed analysis to account for all that. In reality if someone has any similar analysis that gives an efficiency in the same spirit I would find just as acceptable, these are just my thoughts on the various factors one might consider.
